# Even though the cell isn't empty, this code is seeing it as empty

Tags: excel, vba

This code is for something I'm doing at work, it's outputting "No patient reference!" in a MsgBox.
If I remove the if that checks if the cell is IsEmpty I get "Patient not found" in a MsgBox.
It seems like I'm missing something and I'm not sure what, can anyone help?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim emptytest2 As Boolean

emptytest2 = IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("C28").Value)

If emptytest2 = False Then
   MsgBox "No patient reference!"
   End
End If

Dim found As Range
Dim band1 As Range
Dim foundoff As Range
Set found = Sheet2.Columns("B").Find(what:=Sheet1.Range("C28").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    Set band1 = Sheet1.Range("C29")
    MsgBox found & " - Data found for patient in cell " & found.Address
    Set foundoff = Range(found.Address).Offset(, 30)
    band1.Copy
    Sheet2.Range(foundoff.Address).PasteSpecial
Else
    MsgBox "Patient not found"
    End
End If

MsgBox "Successfully added band cutoff data to " & found

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Sheet1.Range("C28").Value` the result of a formula? If so, `IsEmpty` returns `False`. The cell is not empty, it contains a formula. If so, you should simple check it as `If Sheet1.Range("C28").Value <> "" Then`. It will work for both cases (formulas or not).

Comment: `IsEmpty()` returns True for an empty cell so `If emptytest2 = True Then`

Comment: ```Sheet1.Range("C28").Value``` Is a manual input, not the result of a formula no.

Comment: Thanks CDP1802 I've rectified that- can't believe I didn't notice it lol.

Comment: Then, you wrongly used the condition... The best habit to be cultivated is to avoid using of `IsEmpty`. You simple use `if Sheet1.Range("C28").Value = "" Then`. It works for both situations (formulas and manual inputs).

Comment: So ```found = Sheet2.Columns("B").Find(what:=Sheet1.Range("C28").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    Set band1 = Sheet1.Range("C29")
    MsgBox found & " - Data found for patient in cell " & found.Address
    Set foundoff = Range(found.Address).Offset(, 30)
    band1.Copy
    Sheet2.Range(foundoff.Address).PasteSpecial
Else
    MsgBox "Patient not found"
    End
End If
``` searches column B (Where the patient references are) for a match and copies in a manual input to an offset on that row (it's used for data input later on)...

Comment: ...It doesn't seem to find it, yet the input is present in the row B on sheet 2

Comment: If you want to change your question, do so by editing your question. You may ruin any comments written, but at least currently nobody has yet written any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ref As Range, found As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set ref = Sheet1.Range("C28")
    If Len(ref.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No patient reference!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    Set found = Sheet2.Columns("B:B").Find(what:=ref.Value, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Patient Ref '" & ref.Value & "' not found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set rng = found.Offset(, 30) ' col AF
        rng.Value = ref.Offset(1) ' C29
        MsgBox "Patient Ref: '" & ref.Value & "' found in cell " & found.Address
    End If
    MsgBox "Successfully added " & rng.Value & " to " & rng.Address

End Sub
```